# Keras neural net for video classification layer incompatible with the layer: expected ndim=5, found ndim=4. Full shape received: (None, 120, 120, 3)

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, neural-network

I am working on a video classification problem. My neural network stack looks like below:

```
model = Sequential()

model.add(TimeDistributed(Conv2D(64, (3,3), padding='same', activation='relu'), input_shape=(60, 120, 120, 3)))
model.add(TimeDistributed(MaxPooling2D((2, 2), strides=(2, 2))))

model.add(TimeDistributed(Conv2D(128, (3,3), padding='same', activation='relu')))
model.add(TimeDistributed(MaxPooling2D((2, 2), strides=(2, 2))))

model.add(TimeDistributed(Conv2D(256, (3,3), padding='same', activation='relu')))
model.add(TimeDistributed(MaxPooling2D((2, 2), strides=(2, 2))))

model.add(TimeDistributed(Flatten()))

model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(LSTM(256, dropout=0.5))
model.add(Dense(6, activation='softmax'))
```

I compile the model using the following options:

```
model.compile(Adam(0.0001), 'sparse_categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
```

The problem comes here:

```
X_train.shape # (60, 120, 120, 3) -> 60 frames, 120x120 height and width, 3 rgb channels
X_target.shape # (60,) -> each of the 60 frames have an integer label
model.fit(X_train, x_target, epochs=20) -> gives error, expected ndim=5, found ndim=4. Full shape received: (None, 120, 120, 3)
```

This is how I understand it. I defined the input shape to be (60, 120, 120, 3), and it adds a batch size to it internally, making it 5D. Then, when fitting to the model, it needs a 5D shape, but the shape of X_train is 4D. I tried np.expand_dims(X_train, axis=0) to make it 5D, did not work, and explored a lot on the internet. Please help.

Comment: Use X_train=tf.ones(([6,60,120,120,3]))
and x_target=tf.ones(([6]))
and after that model.fit(X_train, x_target, epochs=1) to be sure the data shapes are OK. After success follow this structure with your data to go forward.

Answer (score 0):

A tip to dig in to the "incompatibility" -problems with keras neural network; insert extra "test_output" command to the code as exemplified below, and this way find - sometimes partially by try & error - the correct data in and data out shapes.

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras import layers
from keras.layers import Dense, GlobalAveragePooling2D, Conv2D, MaxPooling2D, Flatten, Dropout, LSTM
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import TimeDistributed

model = Sequential()

model.add(TimeDistributed(Conv2D(64, (3,3), padding='same', activation='relu'), input_shape=(60, 120, 120, 3)))
model.add(TimeDistributed(MaxPooling2D((2, 2), strides=(2, 2))))

model.add(TimeDistributed(Conv2D(128, (3,3), padding='same', activation='relu')))
model.add(TimeDistributed(MaxPooling2D((2, 2), strides=(2, 2))))

model.add(TimeDistributed(Conv2D(256, (3,3), padding='same', activation='relu')))
model.add(TimeDistributed(MaxPooling2D((2, 2), strides=(2, 2))))

model.add(TimeDistributed(Flatten()))

model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(LSTM(256, dropout=0.5))
model.add(Dense(6, activation='softmax'))

model.compile('adam', 'sparse_categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
#model.compile('adam', 'mse', metrics=['accuracy'])

#Let's test the structure experimentally...
test_output=model(tf.ones(([1,60,120,120,3])))
model.summary()

#input of those:
X_train=tf.ones(([6,60,120,120,3]))
x_target=tf.ones(([6]))

model.fit(X_train, x_target, epochs=1)
```

Comment: Thank you, I do really appreciate your time! Is there a reason you chose 6? Just divide 60 by 10?

Comment: The number "6" as a number was just a test, "the first number found from the keyboard"...just use whatever number. But - I think you should check the structure of the network. With current configuration (sparse_categorical_crossentropy as a loss function) the output is not logical according to your network output (6 outputs?). I do not know your research problem, but check that. If you need to keep the current network structure change the loss function to "mse" (in example) ... and you can apply output of size of length 6. If not, change the last layer size...etc.